# Price resolver save custom field

Tags: 8, commerce

I would like to update a custom field, added to my order items, in the price resolver process. The price resolver process do some sort of queries to select the right price and this selection has a key that I want to save in the custom field.
I'm not sure how could I alter the order line item after the right price was selected.

Comment: How are you doing the price resolver? Custom code or contrib module?

Comment: With a custom module. In "resolve" function I calculate de new price and return the new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You price resolver should have something like

```
if (isset($result['price'])) {
    return new Price((string) $result['price'], $context->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode());
}
```

Before your price resolver's `return` line put:

```
$cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
$cart = $cart_provider->getCart('default');
$order_items = $cart->order_items->referencedEntities();
foreach ($order_items as $order_item) { 
  if (!empty($order_item->field_custom)) {
    $order_item->field_custom->value = 'Hello World'; // set new value
    $cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');
    $cart_manager->updateOrderItem($cart, $order_item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works like a charm.